# Matrix multiplication when one dimension is much larger than the other

Tags: algorithm, matrix-multiplication

So I read that Strassen's matrix multiplication algorithm has complexity O(n^2.8)
but it works only if A is n x n and B is n x n
What if 
A is m x n and B is n x o
and m is much much bigger than n and o but n and o is still very big
Padding with zeroes might make the multiplication take longer

I doing a project that requires multiplication of such a matrix so I was hoping to get some advice
Should I use the conventional algorithm or is there a way to modify Strassen's algorithm to do it faster?

Comment: How large do your n o m could be?

Answer (score 1):

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm

> - A product of size [2N x N] * [N x 10N] can be done as 20 separate [N x N] * [N x N] operations, arranged to form the result;
> - A product of size [N x 10N] * [10N x N] can be done as 10 separate [N x N] * [N x N] operations, summed to form the result.
>
> These techniques will make the implementation more complicated, compared to simply padding to a power-of-two square; however, it is a reasonable assumption that anyone undertaking an implementation of Strassen, rather than conventional, multiplication, will place a higher priority on computational efficiency than on simplicity of the implementation.